# Does Firebase provide access token for consuming Google API's (Contacts, Calender)?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, firebase, google-contacts-api, google-oauth

I have this code for accessing Google Contacts API using firebase.
It authenticates the user and returns the access_token but it does not seem to work accessing the Contacts API(I am using AngularFire). Here is the code:

```
var ref = new Firebase("<<FIREBASE-APP>>");
$scope.click = function() {
    ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function (error, authData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        } else {
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
            console.log(authData.google.accessToken);
            var resource = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&access_token=" + authData.google.accessToken;
            $.getJSON(resource,function (response) {
                        console.log(resource);
                    });
        }
```

The error received is:
 https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&access_token… 401 (OK)

Here is the format of authData received:

```
-auth
   -provider
   -uid
-expires
-google
    -accessToken
    -displayName
    -id
    -cacheduserprofile
-provider
-token
-uid
```

Comment: try key instead of access_token

Comment: Not working with key too.

Comment: are you sure https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default is the right url?  I am digging in the documentation now.

Comment: shouldn't it be more like https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/liz%40gmail.com/full

Comment: **default** is used when the user is already authenticated.